# WooCommerce renaming a digital download file

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've been using woocommerce to sell a few digital goods. I have set the following setting "Append a unique string to filename for security" And I was wondering if there is a way to rename the file back to it's original name when the customer downloads it.

For example the filename is product-9j978f.zip and when the customer downloads it would be renamed to product.zip instead.

Thank you and any help would be gladly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code

```php
/**
 * Change the downloadable file name
 *
 * @param string $filename Downloadable file name.
 * @param int    $product_id WC product id.
 * @return string
 */
function change_woocommerce_file_download_filename( $filename, $product_id ) {
    // Get the file extension from the processed file name.
    $filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename );

    // You can generate a new file using Product ID if you need to.
    $new_file_name = 'New File Name';

    // Join the new file name with file extension with (.).
    return join( '.', array( $new_file_name, $filetype['ext'] ) );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_file_download_filename', 'change_woocommerce_file_download_filename', 10, 2 );
```

You get 2 parameters in this filter hook. `1: Filename` `2: Product ID` then you can do the name change according to your need and return the file name.

**NOTE:** new file name should have a `file extension` with it.